# I have trouble with quicksort algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have problems with Quicksort algorithm. I have read on the internet about it on different pages, also Wikipedia. But they explained not too much in detail.
I have understood their examples when you choose the very last element as pivotelement. In this case you choose two other variables `i, j`, where `i` will go through array till it finds an element greater than the pivotelement and the `j` till it finds an element which is lower than the pivotelement. Found, we switch the elements where `i,j` show on, and continue...

My question is, which element you firstly choose as `i,j`? Let's say we have this array given and the pivotelement is `1`:

9 **1** 4 2 0 7

What is my `i`, what is my `j`?

I would think the very first element is `i`, so `9`
 and `j` is the last element in array, so `7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia explains it reasonably well:

> The original partition scheme described by C.A.R. Hoare uses two
>   indices that start at the ends of the array being partitioned, then
>   move toward each other, until they detect an inversion

So the answer is yes, set `i` to the first and `j` to the last element of the array and move them until they meet, that is the basic of the partition part of quicksort algorithm.

Whenever you are not sure, it is good to check the exact code. There are several variations, you can find one e.g. [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort):

```
function quicksort(array)
    if length(array) > 1
        pivot := select any element of array
        left := first index of array
        right := last index of array
        while left ≤ right
            while array[left] < pivot
                left := left + 1
            while array[right] > pivot
                right := right - 1
            if left ≤ right
                swap array[left] with array[right]
                left := left + 1
                right := right - 1
        quicksort(array from first index to right)
        quicksort(array from left to last index)
```

As you can see, `left` and `right` (equivalent to yours `i` and `j`) are set to first and last index of array.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is start at (0) and (length of list - 1), respectively.

**SPOILER (don't read code below or click the link if you don't want a solution in JavaScript, and would rather figure it out yourself using the information I provided in my first statement).**

Take a look at my quicksort algorithm in JavaScript [here](https://github.com/lansana/grokking-algorithms/blob/master/4-quicksort/javascript/quicksort1.js).

Here is an example just for future reference:

```
function quicksort(items, left, right) {
    if (items.length > 1) {
        left = typeof left !== 'number' ? 0 : left;
        right = typeof right !== 'number' ? items.length - 1 : right;

        let index = partition(items, left, right);

        if (left < index - 1) {
            quicksort(items, left, index - 1);
        }

        if (index < right) {
            quicksort(items, index, right);
        }
    }

    return items;
}

function swap(items, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    let temp = items[firstIndex];
    items[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    items[secondIndex] = temp;
}

function partition(items, left, right) {
    let pivot = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
        i = left,
        y = right;

    while (i <= y) {
        while(items[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while(items[y] > pivot) {
            y--;
        }

        if (i <= y) {
            swap(items, i, y);
            i++;
            y--;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

let arr = [10, 3, 7, 5, 9, 2, 8, 1, 6, 4];

console.log(quicksort(arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```